# If I use Adobe Premiere Pro for video editing, does it matter what screen capture software I use?

Tags: premiere, video-editor, screen-casting

The reason I ask is because I’m choosing between these two screen capture software packages: Camtasia ($250) and FilmoraScrn ($19.99). I will capture my screen to a great extent in the months ahead.

Camtasia has more advanced editing functionality than FilmoraScrn, however it may not make sense to use either of them for editing in the long run. I want to avoid potentially over-spending by buying Camtasia if I find its editing functionality unsatisfactory compared to Adobe Premiere Pro.

So if I use Adobe Premiere Pro for video editing, does it truly matter what screen capture software I use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Premiere for editing, there is no point in looking at the editing advantages, they won't be higher than Premiere's capabilities for sure.

[Some polls](https://www.trustradius.com/compare-products/camtasia-vs-filmora) have Filmora lower in rating, but the only issues were with editing.

I was making screen capture for programming videos, and on Mac, I wasn't using anything but quick time player, since 100% of editing goes to Premiere, where you can do literary everything.

Answer (score 1):

I use Open Broadcast Software, it's free!

https://obsproject.com/

To answer your question directly, the videos exported from both of those applications are compatible with Premiere Pro.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be editing in premiere, then it doesn't matter which screen capture software you use. Even if your screen capture software outputs a video file that is incompatible with Premiere by default, you can use a free tool like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert that file into something Premiere can handle. I found this ffmpeg command in the answer to [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/how-to-encode-apple-prores-on-windows-or-linux) that would probably handle whatever video you threw at it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le output.mov
```

Just replace `input.avi` and `output.avi` with your filename and desired output filename. There's much more customization that you can do with ffmpeg, and deeper information in that answer about [ProRes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#ProRes) that isn't relevant here. All you really need to worry about are the recording features of your screen recording software. If you're on a mac, I'd suggest [Screenflick](https://www.araelium.com/screenflick-mac-screen-recorder) as a recorder. It doesn't have editing capabilities like Camtasia, but it has some pretty great export options for keypress overlays and mouse adjustments.